# pythonでオブジェクト名を文字列の結合で作るにはどうすればよいか

Tags: python

```
for (i, num) in enumerate("one", "two", "three"):
    mozi + num =  i
```

みたいな感じで、オブジェクト名をmozioneの様にしたいです

Comment: ディクショナリでダメな理由は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

文字列をコードとして実行することはセキリティ的に推奨されませんが`exec`を使って以下のようにできます．

```
mozi = "mozi"
for (i, num) in enumerate(["one", "two", "three"]):
     exec("{0}{1} = i".format(mozi,num))

print(mozione)   # ==> 0
print(mozitwo)   # ==> 1
print(mozithree) # ==> 2
```

他の方がご回答されているように名前空間を直接操作する方法もありますが恐らくそれも推奨されないと思います． 例えば実現したいことが文字列から数値へのマップを保持したいということなら辞書を使うなど他の方法を考えたほうがよいかと思います．

Comment: ありがとうございます。
セキュリティ的にとはどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: 任意のコードが実行される危険性があるからです．例えばユーザの入力した文字列を変数名にする場合に実行可能なコードを入力される場合などです．

Answer (score 0):

止めた方がよいですが、方法は色々あります。

```
>>> globals()['foo'] = 1
>>> foo
1
```